# Does innerHTML work in IE9?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a html statement:

```
 <b>Node:</b>&nbsp;&nbsp;<h16 id= "test_text" >""</h16>
```

There is a button conorller also. On a click of button I  m calling a javascript function that will set the value of above controller("test_text"). For this i m using innerHTML.

```
document.getElementById('test_text').innerHTML="Hello";
```

This works fine in Mozilla firefox and Chrome but doesnt work in IE9. How can i fix it?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/G4Dzf/ works fine.

Comment: there were cases that innerHTML is not working based on my experience. That's jQuery to the rescue. For functions that are not supported by all browsers we prefer using jQuery since you don't have to worry about cross-browser compatibility

Comment: What's the error you're getting?

Comment: probably because there is no h16 header element

Comment: Seeing `<h16>` makes me think you're working in invalid HTML. In such circumstances, DOM manipulation is just not reliable. There's no way to say how the browser will fix the DOM tree.

Comment: jsfiddle.net/G4Dzf/3 Look here. what i want to do is on a lcick on "hello" link i want to display the value of test_text

Answer (score 0):

You can use jquery  and use `$('#test_text').html("Hello");`

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/G4Dzf/3/ Look here. what i want to do is on a lcick on "hello" link i want to display the value of test_text.

Comment: Sorry I can't clearly understand what are you trying to acheive

Answer (score 0):

hi it's working fine for all browser

and you can check

```
LIVE DEMO
```

http://www.jsfiddle.net/xCaNA/4/

Comment: www.jsfiddle.net/G4Dzf/3 Actually what i want to do is on a lcick on "hello" link i want to display the value of test_text

Comment: can you please explain me more , which value you want to display and where ?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/G4Dzf/3/ i want to set the value of test_text on click of button.

Comment: initially the div style will b none. Aftre click on link the div will be enabled(block) and the value of test_text will be set.

Comment: it's compulsory to use javascript?

Comment: other wise you should used jquery
$("#test_text").html("value you want to set it");